# Auto-complete in pgAdmin: how to get it to automatically appear?

Tags: pgadmin

It looks like
auto-complete is only activated after hitting ctrl + space https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.12/keyboard_shortcuts.html

This is unexpected to me: not quite as "auto" as I would expect an auto-complete feature to be. Is there a way to avoid having to hit ctrl + space to activate auto-complete?

Comment: Do you have any news? I also hope to see this feature one day (it is still not available in the settings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question, however it comes up as one of the top google search results when looking for e.g. "pgadmin autocomplete automatically".  There is a setting in pgAdmin under File -> Preferences -> Query Tool -> Auto completion where you can toggle it to Autocomplete on key press.

[image]